# XMPP I need to send Typing state via XMPP Chat on specific chat Dialogue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

My Requirement is that two users have 2 or more than 2 different dialogue but user are same. so when one can type at that time another one get typing state in all chat dialogue associated with that. bellow is my code on the Sent method

```
-(void)xmpp_SendTypingNotification:(BOOL)isTyping toFriendID:(NSString*)recieverId{
    XMPPMessage * xMessage = [[XMPPMessage alloc] initWithType:@"chat" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:strAddDomain(recieverId)]];
    isTyping?[xMessage addComposingChatState]:[xMessage addInactiveChatState];
    [self.xmppStream sendElement:xMessage];
}
```

or receive code is

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    if ([message isErrorMessage]) {
        return;
    }

    if ([message hasChatState]){
        if (!_arrTypingUsersIDs) {
            _arrTypingUsersIDs=[NSMutableArray new];
        }

        NSString *otherUserID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[message.fromStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"][0]];

        NSInteger typingStatus=[message hasComposingChatState]?1:0;
        [self xmpp_setTypingStatus:typingStatus ofUser:otherUserID];

    }
}
```

Comment: What is dialog? Is it a xmpp room(xep-0045)?

Comment: i am using XMPPFramework for a chat.

Comment: I know, but I did not get what is a dialog in your case. Is it your own entity or is it somethin from the XMPPFramework

Answer (score 1):

you have to use [XEP-0085](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) for sending and receiving chat states(like is typing or pause typing).

In XMPPFramework if you want to send *is typing* chat state just send a message and use `message.addaddComposingChatState()` to add composing state to a message.

When you receive it in your second client you can check if the message is chat state or not using `message.hasChatState` or `message.message.hasComposingChatState` or `hasPausedChatState`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it works this way is because you send this status every time to other user:

```
[XMPPJID jidWithString:strAddDomain(recieverId)]]
```

and not in context of particular dialog.

If you have a 1-1 chat then your solution is right for it.

If you have a group chat (by using [XEP-0045](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html)), then you need to send the typing statuses to group room JID:

```
XMPPMessage *xMessage = [[XMPPMessage alloc] init];
isTyping ? [xMessage addComposingChatState] : [xMessage addInactiveChatState];
[someXMPPRoom sendMessage:xMessage];
```

So only users in this particular chat room will receive your statuses

Here is a link to [XEP-0045 implementation at XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0045)

Comment: my query is that i.e. you and I are working in 2 mission, I want to chat for a first mission so it will send typing state to both missions chatbox for. maybe you and I participate in more than 2 mission also. so how can I send typing state in particular mission chat box.

Comment: You have 2 solutions: 1) use different group chat for each mission 2) include some custom parameter into the typing statuses messages to identify which mission it's connected to

Comment: Ok, now I start with one custom object class method as you said.